# Laravel 5: Insert image urls into column as array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, file, laravel-5

I am building an application using Laravel 5 where I want to insert several image urls within an array separated by commas. This would be placed in a column on the database. The files are successfully uploaded to my AWS S3 bucket, but it's now the input to the database. I tried using Laravel's array_add helper but I get an error stating I am missing argument 2. I am wondering how would I be able to achieve this. My current alternate solution is to put the images with the post id and use the relationship to connect them together.

For reference: The column I intend to place the images is picgallery, and the insert is done using $newproperty['picgallery'] variable.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //establish random generated string for gallery_id
    $rando = str_random(8);

    //input all data to database 
    $data = $request->all(); 

    $newproperty['title'] = $data['title']; 
    $newproperty['address'] = $data['address']; 
    $newproperty['city'] = $data['city'];
    $newproperty['province'] = $data['province']; 
    $newproperty['contact_person'] = Auth::user()->id; 
    $newproperty['gallery_id'] = $rando; 
    $newproperty['property_description'] = $data['description']; 

    if($request->hasfile('images')) {  
       $files = $request->file('images'); 

       //storage into AWS 
       foreach ($files as $file) { 
           $uploadedFile = $file;
           $upFileName = time() . '.' . $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName(); 
           $filename = strtolower($upFileName); 

           $s3 = \Storage::disk('s3'); 
           $filePath = 'properties/' . $rando . '/' . $filename;

           $s3->put($filePath, file_get_contents($uploadedFile), 'public');

           $propicurl = 'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/cebuproperties/' . $filePath; 

           $array = array_add(['img'=> '$propicurl']);

           $newproperty['picgallery'] = $array; 

       } 
    } 

    Properties::create($newproperty); 

    return redirect('/properties');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

array_add requires 3 parameters

$array = array_add($array, 'key', 'value');
(https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-array-add)

For example

```
$testArray = array('key1' => 'value1');
$testArray = array_add($testArray, 'key2', 'value2');
```

and you will get

```
[
     "key1" => "value1",
     "key2" => "value2",
]
```

You might not be able to use array_add in this case.

I think in order to fix your issue, fix your foreach loop to be something like this

```
//storage into AWS 
// init the new array here
$array = [];
foreach ($files as $file) { 
       $uploadedFile = $file;
       $upFileName = time() . '.' . $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName(); 
       $filename = strtolower($upFileName); 

       $s3 = \Storage::disk('s3'); 
       $filePath = 'properties/' . $rando . '/' . $filename;

       $s3->put($filePath, file_get_contents($uploadedFile), 'public');

       $propicurl = 'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/cebuproperties/' . $filePath; 

       // change how to use array_add
       array_push($array, array('img' => $propicurl));
       // remove the below line
       // $array = array_add($array, 'img', $propicurl);
} 

// move this assignment out of foreach loop
$newproperty['picgallery'] = $array;
```

Comment: just tried this. Got an undefined variable: array error.

Comment: You need to put an array initialise on top of foreach loop 

    $array = [];

Please check the latest code on the answer

Comment: Come to think of this again. We inserted a duplicate key into the same array, which means, in the end, you will get an array with only 1 element. I think we might use array_push instead. I'll update my answer